# POST запрос без формы

Tags: php

Как передать данные методом пост без формы, при этом чтобы пользователя перекидывало на страницу на которую передаем данные?

Этапы:
1. Клиент заполняет форму
2. Происходит обработка введенных данных
3. В зависимости от введенных данных выбирается url на который будет перенаправлен пользователь и отправлены данные в виде post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('html').html('<form action="/2.php" name="vote" method="post" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="name" value="яндекс" /></form>');

document.forms['vote'].submit();
```

Сделал так.

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то как-то так

```
$('#f-form__callback').on('submit', function(e){
                    var fdata = $(this).serialize();
                    var ajaxUrl = '';
                    e.preventDefault(); // блокируем стандартную отправку формы
                    // ваша обработка данных в которых вы определяете куда отправить данные
                    // в зависимости от ваших обработок устанавливаете ajaxUrl
                    if (someVar = 'someValue') ajaxUrl = '/some/url'; 
                    if (ajaxUrl !== '') {
                    // если вы поняли куда отправлять данные, то делаем это через ajax
                    $.ajax({
                        url: ajaxUrl,
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        data: fdata,
                        success: function (data) {
                            // в data содержится адрес, куда вы будете перенаправлены, если у вас есть эта обработка на сервере
                            if (data) {
                                window.location.href = data;
                            } else {
                                window.location.href = ajaxUrl;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте `action` у родительской формы в зависимости от введённых данных, и стандартно отправьте её методом `post`. Засовывать аякс в событие `submit`, а потом перенаправлять пользователя при помощи `location.href`, как советуют товарищи ниже, крайне не рекомендую.

Comment: Поделитесь, пожалуйста, почему именно "крайне не рекомендуете"?

Comment: Потому что Вы засовываете асинхронный код в синхронный и это плохая практика. Иногда так делают когда это действительно оправданно, тут товарищу нужно просто подменить `action`.

Comment: Вы так и не пояснили, почему это плохая практика. С точки зрения лояльности пользователей это совершенно не так